# Не работают :before and :after в IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Есть калькулятор,который хорошо отображается в современных браузерах. Но в ie8 работает некорректно! Почему то пропали :before и :after скобки у .brackets. Слетело отображение абсолютно позиционированных букв у таблиц да и вообще он не хочет использовать `width: 100%; text-align:center`. Видимо position relative не хочет применяться. Как это можно исправить?

```
   .matrix_b {
  tbody{
    &:before{
      content: 'B';
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 20px;
      bottom: -50px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что нет кода. Даже по ссылке нет кода, только 404.

Comment: @Qwertiy ссылку поправил. Не думаю что будет толк от данного кода. гораздо легче и понятнее зайти в ie и нажать f12.

Comment: @Drop, в ie в режиме совместимости с 8 все показывается нормально

Comment: @Grundy странно в чистой 8. Он кок раз не хочет выравнивать before и after. Ну и не отображает скобки вокруг таблиц.
https://yadi.sk/i/wkx5DLPMrouzU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, очень плохо в ie8 работает поддержка before и after у таблиц. сделал данную структуру и все стало прекрасно отображаться.
Написано на less

```css
.matrix_b_wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.b_name{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  bottom: -50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.matrix_b_cover {
//  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
  .str_inp{
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    input{
      width: 38px;
      height: 38px;
      padding-left: 6px;
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
      border-top: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
      &:focus{
        border:2px solid #5199db;
      }
    }
  }
.brackets{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  &:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    bottom: -6px;
    right: -7px;
    border-right: 2px solid #222;
    width: 10px;
    
    border-top: 2px solid #222;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
  }
  &:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    bottom: -6px;
    left: -7px;
    width: 10px;
   
    border-top: 2px solid #222;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
    border-left: 2px solid #222;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="matrix_b_wrapper">
      <div class="matrix_b_cover">
        <div class="brackets">
        <span class="b_name">B</span>
        <table class="matrix_b " id="matrix_b">

           <tr>
            <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b1,1">
            </td>
             <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b1,2">
             </td>
             <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b1,3">
             </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b2,1">
            </td>
            <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b2,2">
            </td>
            <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b2,3">
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
```